# The below code gets compiled but when foo is called invalid opcode error is thrown

Tags: contract-design, storage, arrays, struct, memory

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.7.0;
contract Mycontract{
    uint256 a;
    struct User
    {  string name; }
    User[] users;
    function foo() public{
      User storage user=users[0];
      user.name="hey";
    }
    function get() public view returns(string memory)
    {   return users[0].name; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused by this : `User storage user=users[0];`

You try to assign to `user` the first element of the `users` array but you can't access an empty array.

If you want to push your object into the array you can use `array.push()`.

Comment: Do User storage user = User("hey) then users.push(user).

Comment: it is giving me the following error: Type struct Mycontract.User memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type struct Mycontract.User storage pointer.
User storage user= User("hey");
^----------------------------^

Comment: Change "storage" to "memory".

Comment: yes its working but can you please tell me the reason for doing so?